# Need to generate the getter and setter for QueryParam

Tags: java, hibernate, rest, jersey, hibernate-mapping

I need to save the Queryparam in database using hibernate.

For that I need to produce the getter and setter of the parameters.

While doing the same , facing [error](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+sparshkhandelwal610/posts/iZKG14MB25r?pid=6131804064950549522&oid=110362168537815837905)(can not post it:::: less than 10 reputation)

```
public Response responseMsg( @PathParam("parameter") String parameter,
        @DefaultValue("Nothing to say") @QueryParam("firstname") String firstname ,@QueryParam("lastname") String lastname,@QueryParam("emailid") String emailid,@QueryParam("password") String password) {
```

Please help me with the approach.

What I think , First I need to create POJO and then in the setter assign the value of Queryparam to the variable of POJO.

Answer (score 1):

First Create Entity Class, that is annotation based class.U have to make attributes as per your `@queryparam` attributes.
 Create getter and setter in it. then simply u can save it using Hibernate SessionFactory.